# React setState wont re-render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm working on a self project React for front-end and node for back-end, part of the app is that when a user submits an image url it counts the entries and it updates in the server then it should re-render on the front-end to the screen. The problem is it doesn't re-render, i have console.log tested and everything works from the server side, the problem is in the setState in react wont re-render and i'm hoping any one help me understand why it is not working?

Here is the code related to my problem

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imgUrl: '',
      box: {},
      route: 'signin',
      isSignedIn: false,
      user: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        entries: 0,
        joined: '',
      },
    }
  }
  loadUser = data => {
    this.setState({
      user: {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email,
        entries: data.entries,
        joined: data.joined,
      },
    })
  }

  onButtonSubmit = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/image', {
      method: 'put',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id: this.state.user.id,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json)
      .then(count => {
        this.setState({ ...this.state.user, entries: count })
      })



      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}

 render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation
        isSignedIn={this.state.isSignedIn}
        onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}
      />
      {this.state.route === 'home' ? (
        <div>
          <Rank
            name={this.state.user.name}
            entries={this.state.user.entries}
          />
          <ImageLinkForm
            onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
            onButtonSubmit={this.onButtonSubmit}
          />
          <FaceRecognition box={this.state.box} imgUrl={this.state.imgUrl} />
        </div>
      ) : this.state.route === 'signin' ? (
        <Signin loadUser={this.loadUser} onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} />
      ) : (
        <Register
          loadUser={this.loadUser}
          onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

this code is suppose to print the entries count on the screen but its not

```
this.setState({...this.state.user, entries: count})
```

here is the server side where entries gets updated and sent to the front-end

```
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body
  let found = false
  database.users.forEach(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      found = true
      user.entries++
      return res.json(user.entries)
    }
  })
  if (!found) {
    res.status(400).json('not found')
  }
})
```

here is the rank Component where entries gets printed

```
import React from 'react';

 const Rank = ({ name, entries}) => {

return (
 <div>
  <div className='rank'>
  {`${name} your current rank is...`}
  </div>
  <div className='white f1 '>
    {entries}
  </div>
 </div>

  );
 }
 export default Rank;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to spread whole user object. `setState` merges updates to state. So, declare only changes in `setState`. By the way, `'http://localhost:3001/image'` gives you all user related data or only count?

Comment: It gives me entries count (which is basically a number from server).

Comment: Well, if until `setState` everything is fine, then try to change `this.setState({...this.state.user, entries: count})` to this `this.setState({user: {...this.state.user, entries: count}})`

Comment: yeah that should fix, but now i get a warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Comment: I also tried this.setState(Object.assign(this.state.user, {entries: count})) but it also gave me same warning.

Comment: ok. now check your state after update and props which are using that update. As I understood <Rank> component is using entries count. Whatever. The problem should be fixed by examining render functions. Somewhere instead of row data (e.g. number) you are getting function or something sort of. Try to trace errors. Watch where it fires. You can even use console.log-s.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see any use of doing ...this.state.user in setState So

Change

```
  this.setState({...this.state.user, entries: count})
```

To

```
  this.setState({entries: count})
```

Comment: Tried it, still entries count does not re-render.

Comment: Actually, by doing this, you create new prop in state named `entries`, which is out of `user` object in state. But you're using `this.state.user.entries` in your rendering.